# how to attach a external style sheet with evary page of asp

Tags: css, asp-classic

I have a CSS file called mystyle.css.  I want to attach with each and every page of my application in asp.

How Can I do this?

Comment: Can you disambiguate the question by adding either asp-classic or asp.net tag?

Answer (score 1):

at the top of your asp page, then your header page holds the CSS, Javascript etc etc

normally you would have header, footer in a seperate file and my method used to be to create one single asp page, then split the code into 3 pieces.

1. the header
2. the page
3. my footer

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ASP.NET Master Pages Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) it may be what you are looking for.

> ASP.NET master pages allow you to
>   create a consistent layout for the
>   pages in your application. A single
>   master page defines the look and feel
>   and standard behavior that you want
>   for all of the pages (or a group of
>   pages) in your application. You can
>   then create individual content pages
>   that contain the content you want to
>   display. When users request the
>   content pages, they merge with the
>   master page to produce output that
>   combines the layout of the master page
>   with the content from the content
>   page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. ASP does not support master pages.

Comment: Problem is ASP is currently used in an ambiguous way, even Microsoft employees are now using the term ASP to refer to ASP.NET.  I've given up trying to tidy up ASP tags and have resorted to ensuring that either asp-classic or asp.net is also present.  In this there isn't enough info in the question to make a determination

Comment: Checking his recent posts, I thought it might actually be "Classic ASP". He's been trying to get ASP pages working in an ASP.NET site.